# How to create a navigation link to another website in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, blogs, jekyll-bootstrap

I am creating a static website in Jekyll. I haven't figured out how to make a link in the header that will link to a another website like Google.com. I want to this to link back to my main website xociety.co.

I looked in the config file and the docs on jekyllrb.com but haven't found anything on this subjects. I only found permalinks and that isn't what I was looking for. If anyone knows this answer, your much appreciated.

I would show a visual example, but I need 10 rep points,which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to do this. Use Markdown. In the config file I can do.

```
Navigation:
- title: Home
 url: /index.html
- title: About
url: http://xociety.co
 - title: Contact
url: /contact
```

and set up the correct configurations for this to work.